# C# Throw and then Continue to Return

Tags: c#

I'm using try/catch in my method. Naturally, if the exception happens it will throw an exception (that I'll need to have for my UnitTest part), but will not return the value.

What I want is for the catch part to do both: throw an exception and also return the value.

Is there a way to do it?

Here is my sample code (and return count is not expected to be '0'):

```
    private int myCount;

    public void DoSomethingMethod()
{
     // Do Something Here
     myCount++;
}

    public int MyMethod ()
            {
                try
                {
                    DoSomethingMethod()
                    return myCount;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                    return myCount; // Do not expect this value to be '0'
                }
            }
```

Here is the test  part which would need both of those (exception and the return count).

```
[Test]
        public void when_expected_count()
        {
            int count= 0;
            Action act = () => count= MyMethod.GetResult();

            act.Should().Throw<Exception>("The method should throw Exception.");
            count.Should().Be(10);
        }
```

Comment: You could create a POCO for it to return with an `error` and `count` properties. Otherwise no.

Comment: You can't do that. What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to throw an exception AND return a value?

Comment: What would it *mean* to both throw and return? What would you expect to happen in the calling method? Would control continue to the next statement (which is what happens when a called method returns) or would it find the appropriate catch block (which is what happens when a called method throws an exception)? It can't do both.

Comment: `throw` and `return` with both exit the method. You have to pick one. One option is to return an object that has both a `Count` property and an `Exception` property, which the client could then use to get the count value and check to see if there was an error.

Comment: Thanks @YuriyFaktorovich, and Jon Skeet. I have updated my original post above, trying to make it more clear (close) to what I'm doing and expecting.

Comment: @JonSkeet Would a `Try[Action]` mimicking pattern used by `.TryParse(string, out int)` be appropriate here?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the inputs. I think I will go with the proposal from RufusL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`throw` and `return` with both exit the method, so you'd have to pick one.

One option would be to return an object that has both a `Count` property and an `Exception` property, so the client could then get the count value and check to see if there was an error:

```
private int myCount;

public class CountWithException
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}

public CountWithException MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // Do something here
        myCount++;

        // Return an object with the count property set
        return new CountWithException {Count = myCount};
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        myCount--;

        // Return an object with both the count AND exception properties set
        return new CountWithException { Count = myCount, Exception = ex};
    }
}
```

Note that a `catch` on the client side will not get triggered with this. The client would then have to do something like:

```
var result = SomeClass.MyMethod();

var count = result.Count;  // Example of getting the 'count' return value

if (result.Exception != null)
{
    // Do something if the method "threw an excpetion"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, this should about pass your test.

```
public void MyMethod (out int myCount)
{
    try
    {
        DoSomethingMethod()
        myCount = 10;//or whatever you need
    }
    catch
    {
        myCount = 10;//or whatever you need
        throw;
    }
}
```

With the test

```
[Test]
public void when_expected_count()
{
    int count = 0;
    Action act = () => MyMethod.GetResult(out count);

    act.Should().Throw<Exception>("The method should throw Exception.");
    count.Should().Be(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was said above you can either return or throw an exception. You can return a type that contains the int and the exception that should have been thrown. But, another option is to inherit the Exception and create a new type of exception that contains a property of the value that should have been returned.
[check out this explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions)

Answer (score -1):

Throwing an Exception always jumps out of the Function an searches for the next handling inside of the call stack. Instead of throwing an exception you could raise an event. Build an event which has the an exception as parameter and raise it when the error occurs. Then you can outside of your class handle it in the calling class.

Comment: Do you have an example of some code using this sort of practice? I don't think I've ever seen code that raises events to signal that an exception happened. It seem highly unusual (and unnecessary?)

Comment: I think, this one is a good example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

Comment: As Parameters of an event you can also use the current exception which you just catched in the catch section, which means the exception is now handled. In the calling class you can now analyse or print the exceptions parameters, whatever you like, because an exception is also just an object.